# Issue with the disply:inline-block; on IE10

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a small issue with IE10 and `display:inline-block`, I have a dropdownbox within a from and this is the css used:

```
.formlayout label span {
      display:inline-block;
      margin:0 0 0 1em;
      text-align:left;
      width:60%;
      zoom:1;
}
```

If I remove the line the dropdownlist behaves normally but when the css is applied the ddl becomes intermittent when one click on it.

Does anyone know of any reason why? And this only happens on Internet Explorer, not in Firefox and Chrome.

I have added the `*display:inline;` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you post your **HTML**? Or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: <fieldset class= clientdetails formlayout> <cc:date runat="server"/> </fieldset> cc:date is a custom control for the dates

Comment: Without a demo, your problem is unrecognized.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar it is kinda hard for me to bring in all the code, if you see what I mean just because there are so many composite controls where let say the cc:date is made up of three ddl and each ddl is made of anthem controls. So all in all I wanted to see if there is anyone who 's ever experienced a similar issue. I tried using jsFiddle, but because of the way the controls are built I can't. Maybe time to call it a day